# ERROR: syntax error at or near "modify" - in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, alter-table

I executed this SQL statement in Postgres

```
alter table user modify column 'distinguishedName1' text;
```

and

```
alter table user modify column distinguishedName1 text;
```

- `user` is the table name
- `distinguishedName1` is the column name with integer data type.

I wanted to modify the data type to boolean or text or varchar(256) etc based on user's input. But when I run the query I get the error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "modify"

Not sure what is the problem. Help required on right query.

Comment: Where [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) did you see the modify keyword?

Comment: "*modify the data type to (...) based on user's input*" that sounds like a horrible idea. What problem is it you are trying to solve with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE "user" ALTER COLUMN distinguishedName1 TYPE text USING code::text;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE "user" ALTER COLUMN distinguishedName1 TYPE text
```

Also do note that the USING is optional. See the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) here:

> The optional USING clause specifies how to compute the new column
>   value from the old; if omitted, the default conversion is the same as
>   an assignment cast from old data type to new. A USING clause must be
>   provided if there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new
>   type.

On a side note try to avoid naming your tables as [reserved keywords](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Comment: I don't think `USING` is required here

Comment: The query "alter table user alter column distinguishedName1 type text using distinguishedName1::text;   works fine for me. But the same query is not working if I try to change data type to integer or boolean.

Answer (score 3):

`POSTGRES` syntax for altering column type :

```
ALTER TABLE user ALTER COLUMN distinguishedName1 TYPE text;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table user Alter column distinguishedName1 text;
```

Syntax mistake , for sql server you have to use alter to modify the column of table